# Relations and fucntions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Hello I do not quite understand how this works, is it possible if someone could help would be appreciated :)

f(x)and g(x) are defined over the real number set R as follows: g(x)=1-x+x2 and
f(x) = ax + b. If g o f(x) = 16x2-12x+3, determine all the possible values of a
and b.

Answer (score 1):

Well
\begin{align}
(g \circ f)(x) &= 1-(ax+b)+(ax+b)^2 \\
               &= 1-ax-b+a^2x^2+2axb+b^2
\end{align}
From which you need to show that
\begin{align}
3   &= 1-b+b^2 \\
-12 &= 2ab-a \\
16 &= a^2  
\end{align}

From which you can find the values for $a, b$.

Comment: No problem, if you're happy, press to accept the answer to close the question. Many thanks!